# accesing request.user in a tabularinline

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a `ModelForm` with multiple `TabularInline`s that I want to use in the admin. I want to know which user changed something using the inlines.

```
class ResourceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    resource  = forms.FileField(widget=CustomImageFile, ...)

    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = ["resource"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop("user")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["resource"].widget.form_instance = self 

    def clean(self):
        # i need the request.user here


class ResourceTabularInline(TabularInline):
    model = Resource
    form = ResourceForm
    
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        formset.user = request.user # <-- I hoped this would be in the kwargs later on
        return formset


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ResourceTabularInline,]
```

unfortunately the key `user` is not in the kwargs of the `__init__()` method this way -> `KeyError`. How can I access the user

Answer (score 0):

It is quite ugly but this can be done by constructing an ad-hoc form class:

```
class ResourceTabularInline(TabularInline):
    model = Resource
    form = ModelForm

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        class ResourceForm(forms.ModelForm):
            user = request.user
            resource = forms.FileField(widget=CustomImageFile)

            class Meta:
                model = Resource
                fields = ['resource']
                self.fields["resource"].widget.form_instance = self

            def clean(self):
                # use self.user
                pass

        return super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs, form=ResourceForm)


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ResourceTabularInline,
    ]
```

But I admit it is ugly, no *really*, very ugly.

Comment: oh geee. yes you are right. This IS ugly. Bot does the job. Always a pleasure.

Comment: @xtlc: well I hope in the future they add a `form_kwargs=` parameter to the formfactory, so that this kan indeed be done more elegantly. So perhaps in the future this answer will (hopefully) get outdated.